# Powershell that generates HTML Fragments

Tags: html, excel, powershell, dashboard

I am currently trying to write a Powershell Script that will read an Excel File and generate HTML fragments. I am using it to generate HTML for a dashboard and the idea is that the script will not have to be changed no matter what new divs are put on the spread sheet due to nesting. I really have no idea where to start. My original script looks like the one below, but it would have to be edited any time a new column or div was put into the file which is why I can not do a CSV file?

```
new-item registration.html -type file
add-content registration.html "<html><head></head><body><div id='registration'>"
new-item bill.html -type file
add-content bill.html "<html><head></head><body><div id='bill'>"
new-item financial.html -type file
add-content financial.html "<html><head></head><body><div id='financial'>"
$csv=(import-csv elements.csv)
foreach($row in $csv){
$name=(get-date).ticks
$registration= $row.registration
$bill= $row.bill
$financial= $row.financial
add-content registration.html "<%="
add-content registration.html $registration
add-content registration.html "%>"
add-content bill.html "<%="
add-content bill.html $bill
add-content bill.html "%>"
add-content financial.html "<%="
add-content financial.html $financial
add-content financial.html "%>"
}
add-content registration.html "</div></body></html>"
add-content bill.html "</div></body></html>"
add-content financial.html "</div></body></html>"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I depends on many things and basically you'll need to figure out the logic for each file and generate the content accordingly. Based on what you already have, I can suggest a shorter way:

```
add-content registration.html "<html><head></head><body><div id='registration'>"
add-content bill.html "<html><head></head><body><div id='bill'>"
add-content financial.html "<html><head></head><body><div id='financial'>"

import-csv elements.csv | foreach{
    add-content registration.html ('<%={0}%>' -f $_.registration)
    add-content bill.html ('<%={0}%>' -f $_.bill)
    add-content financial.html ('<%={0}%>' -f $_.financial)
}

add-content registration.html,bill.html,financial.html "</div></body></html>"
```

You can generalize the above even more, I didn't test it but imo it should work.

```
'registration','bill','financial' | ForEach-Object {

    $page = $_

    add-content "$page.html" "<html><head></head><body><div id='$page'>"

    import-csv elements.csv | foreach{
        add-content "$page.html" ('<%={0}%>' -f $_."$page")
    }

    add-content "$page.html" "</div></body></html>"
}
```

Comment: Unless I am putting your code in the wrong place, it does not work. the idea is to generate html fragments based off the number of items in the csv file.  Each item has its own div.

Comment: Them move the div creation line inside the foreach loop.